# why update and delete query not worked in custom table?

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql

this is custom template. I wrote crud by using wordpress query to sent data in custom table of database and get from database, insert query worked, but update and delete query not working. Below I give update and delete query, please suggest if anyone knows?

data inserted but when refresh, data deleted by itself and not update or delete
this is insert query

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:Form Template page
 */
get_header(); ?>
  <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table= 'wp_contact_form';
         if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $data = array(
            'names' => $_POST['yourname'],
            'emails'    => $_POST['customer_email'],
            'gender' => $_POST['customer_gender'],
            'age' => $_POST['customer_age']
        );

        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data );
        if($success){
            echo 'data has been save' ; 
        }
    else {
            echo "data not save";
        }
        } 
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-12 pb-5">
                    <form method="post">
                        Your name:<input type="text" name="yourname" id="yourname">
                        Your Email:<input type="text" id="customer_email" name="customer_email"/><br>
                            Gender:<input type="radio" name="customer_gender" value="male">Male
                                   <input type="radio" name="customer_gender" value="female">Female<br>
                            Your Age:<input type="text" name="customer_age" id="customer_age"><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                           <input type="submit" name="show" value="Show"> <a href="http://localhost/vishal_nov/edit-form/">show</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
<?php
    get_footer();   
?>
```

this is update and delete query

```
<?php
 /* 
  * Template Name: Show Form Template Page
  */
?>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="POST">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                </tr> 
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $table= 'wp_contact_form';
                $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $table" );

                if(!empty($result)){
                foreach ( $result as $print ) {                                         
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $print->id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->names;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->emails;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->gender;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->age;?></td>
                <td><button class="" name="update">Edit</button></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="'.$print->id.'" class="del_btn">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                } 
                ?>
        </table>
        </form>
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $id= $print->id;
                $table= 'wp_contact_form';
                if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    $data =array(
                            'names' => $_POST['yourname'],
                            'emails'    => $_POST['customer_email'],
                            'gender' => $_POST['customer_gender'],
                            'age' => $_POST['customer_age']
                                );
                    $wherecondition=array(
                                    'id'=>$id
                                );
                $updated=$wpdb->update($table, $data, $wherecondition);

            }   
                
                
                    ?>
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
                 
                 $('.del_btn').click(function(){
                   var el = this;
                               
                   var deleteid = $(this).attr('id');
                 
                   var confirmalert = confirm("Are you sure?");
                   if (confirmalert == true) {
                      // AJAX Request
                      $.ajax({
                        url: 'delete1.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { dell_id:deleteid },
                        success: function(response){

                          if(response == 1){
                        
                        $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                        $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800,function(){
                           $(this).remove();
                        });
                          }
                          else{
                        alert('Invalid ID.');
                          }

                        }
                      });
                  }
                   });

                 });
</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

delete query define in delete.php file but it shows page not found

```
    <?php
global $wpdb;
$table= 'wp_contact_form';
$id=$_POST['dell_id'];
$result = $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $id));

if(!empty($result))
 {
     if($result){
    echo "success";
     }
   
     
}

?>
```

here is screen shot https://prnt.sc/wbgzgt
here is screenshot for error page not found for ajax jquery in console
https://prnt.sc/wc1l4s

Comment: You're trying to update a post where the `id` is `$result->id`, but `$result` is an array of all your rows. It doesn't have an ID. If you want to update a specific row, you need to send the ID as a form field so that you can tell _which_ row needs to be updated.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you should post that as an answer rather than a comment

Comment: I understand little bit, but not completely. please explain your code.

Comment: is update query is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line where you're defining `$id`:

```
<?php
$id= $result->id;
global $wpdb;
```

You're getting the `$id` field in `$result`. `$result` is an array of the objects returned from the database `get_results` call. It looks like you want to use the `$print` variable for the current row in the loop, so `$id = $print->id`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. but there is still something missing, I replace $print with $result, but nothing works

Comment: @vishal Did you mean you replaced $result with $print?

Comment: yes, I replaced

Comment: could you help me @Nicholas Harris